# How to send Multipart response using RestEasy framework

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I am trying to implement a webservice that accepts a json string and based on the key it fetches a .zip file.

Then I need to send the .zip file and a json string bundled in a multipart data.

So basically my response should a multipart object containing two parts

```
1) .zip file
2) json string
```

Here is my current code

```
public class ContentRepo {



@POST
@Path("/fetchModel")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("multipart/mixed")
public Response getContent(String strJson)
{
    Response response = null;
    try{
        JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject(strJson);
        String strAssetName = objJson.getString("assetName");
        if(null != strAssetName){
            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            ResteasyClient restEasyClient = (ResteasyClient) client;
            ResteasyWebTarget target = restEasyClient.target("http://localhost:8091/ContentServer/").path("fetchModel");
            response = target.request()
                    .post(Entity.entity(getMultiPartData("Car"), MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}

public MultipartFormDataOutput getMultiPartData(String strAssetName){

    MultipartFormDataOutput objMultiPartData = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject();

    try{
         if(strAssetName.equalsIgnoreCase("Car")){
            //car assets
            try {
                objMultiPartData.addFormData("file", new FileBody(new File("D:/programs/content_server/Car/Car.zip")), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
                objJson.put("png", "car");  
                objMultiPartData.addFormData("mapping", new StringBody(objJson.toString()), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return objMultiPartData;
}
```

}

However, when the run the above I am not able to fetch the multipart response. Instead a get the below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.<init>(Lorg/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory;)V
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientConfiguration.<init>(ClientConfiguration.java:44)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:347)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ResteasyClientBuilder.build(ResteasyClientBuilder.java:52)
at javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient(ClientBuilder.java:114)
at com.app.wikicontent.WikitudeContentRepo.getARModel(WikitudeContentRepo.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:155)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:257)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:222)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:211)
at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:525)
... 25 more
```

Comment: Post more details on the dependencies you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stack trace is complaining that it can't find a `ResteasyProvider` [constructor](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.0.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/spi/ResteasyProviderFactory.html#ResteasyProviderFactory(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory)) that was not [introduced](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/commit/4db4b30267882f63dbb60fc9d543eb6a956d9fee#diff-1a6497249ed5ac9a48abeb3c4c16cd0dR192) until [`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs/) version 3.0 in order to support [`org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-client`](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-client/).  So you probably have an older version of `resteasy-jaxrs` somewhere on your runtime classpath.  Remove it and make sure that your deployed application has its versions of `resteasy-jaxrs` and `resteasy-client` in sync.